# Error running sonar-scanner via docker image

Tags: sonarqube, sonarqube-scan

I install sonar-scanner via docker on my mac

(https://hub.docker.com/r/sonarsource/sonar-scanner-cli) and I getting the error "You must define the following mandatory properties for 'Unknown': sonar.projectKey".

I have done the following:

1: add a sonar-scanner.properties file in the root of JS project

```
# Required metadata
sonar.projectKey=my-app
sonar.projectName=Franchise
sonar.projectVersion=1.0

# Comma-separated paths to directories with sources (required)
sonar.sources=server/app.js,pages,components
```

2 Installed docker and the scanner

Here my docker command

docker run  --rm  -e SONAR_HOST_URL="https://sonarqube.comp.com/"  -e SONAR.PROJECTKEY="my-app" -v "/git/franchises"  sonarsource/sonar-scanner-cli

Can please let me know how to pass the information correctly.

Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

### Run SonarQube Server as Docker Image:

- `\$ docker pull sonarqube:7.9.4-community`
- `\$ docker run -d --name sonarqube -e SONAR_ES_BOOTSTRAP_CHECKS_DISABLE=true -p 9000:9000 sonarqube:7.9.4-community`
- Log in to http://localhost:9000  (login=admin, password=admin)
- (make sure - sonarqube server is running at localhost:9000)

### Run SonarScanner as Docker Image:

- `\$ docker pull newtmitch/sonar-scanner:4-alpine`
- Goto your root directory of the Project
- ```sh
   \$ docker run -it -v $(pwd):/usr/src --link sonarqube:7.9.4-community newtmitch/sonar-scanner:4-alpine \
       -D sonar.host.url=http://sonarqube:9000 \
       -D sonar.scm.provider=git  \
       -D sonar.projectBaseDir=./src \
       -D sonar.sources=. \
       -D sonar.projectName='Test-Project'
  ```
- (NOTE: Above I assume that your source code is inside- src folder, if not please change accordingly)
- Go to  http://localhost:9000 You will now see a new project - "Test-Project" which has completely analyzed the source code that you ran from your root directory.
- Documentation [click](https://github.com/newtmitch/docker-sonar-scanner)

### Using "sonarqube-scanner" Package (Alternative for SonarScanner, specific to js/ts language):

- `\$ npm i -D sonarqube-scanner`
- In package.json add a new script: `"sonar": "node sonar-project.js"`
- add a file in your root-directory:   ***sonar-project.js***
- Copy following code in sonar-project.js:

  ```
   const sonarqubeScanner = require('sonarqube-scanner');
   sonarqubeScanner({
   serverUrl: 'http://localhost:9000',
   options: {
     'sonar.sources': 'src',
     'sonar.tests': 'src',
     'sonar.inclusions': 'src/**/*.ts', // Entry point of your code
     'sonar.test.inclusions': 'src/**/*.spec.ts,src/**/*.spec.jsx',
     },
   }, () => {
   console.log('Error Occurred while scanning');                    
   });
  ```
- `\$ npm run sonar`
- Documentation [click](https://github.com/bellingard/sonar-scanner-npm)

Answer (score 1):

A bit late, but here is a solution:

`docker run --rm -e SONAR_HOST_URL="https://sonarqube.comp.com/" -v "/git/franchises" sonarsource/sonar-scanner-cli -Dsonar.projectKey=my-app`

As stated in https://github.com/SonarSource/sonar-scanner-cli-docker/issues/26, you can append any `-Dsonar.xxx` property.

Comment: Thank you for pointing me into this direction! I needed to add a space between `-D` and `sonar.projectKey=my-app` to make it work. Otherwise I got `ERROR: Unrecognized option: .projectKey=my-app` which is pretty odd as the official docs all use `-Dsonar.xxx`.

Comment: If you use Windows, it's best to use `-D "arg=value"`.

Answer (score 1):

I'm late to the party, but you can also use the `.properties` file, except it should be named `sonar-project.properties`.